# Always check if user is logged in

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-views

Right now, I am using the code below to check if user is not logged in.
If not he is redirected to the login page.

```
from .account_controller import logged_in
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def some_view(request):
    # Check if user is not logged in.
    if not logged_in(request):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')

    # If the user is logged in, then continue
    pass
```

What I want is to **not** include this code every time I am going to make a new method.
How can I make it **view-wide**, if not, **app-wide**, so that every time I create a new method, it checks if the user is logged in?

All answers are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: read official documentation: [The login_required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator)

Comment: Thank you @furas . I understand how it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has already built login_required decorator for purpose of this

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required()
def some_view(request):
    pass
```

If the user isn’t logged in, redirect to settings.LOGIN_URL

[login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required)